# Drop in nested tables?

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to drop a specified number of elements from a 'table

```
tab = {{0.2421321014434619`, 0.27498187797759344`, 
0.28728191976974427`, 0.29287047412596257`, 
0.3494318810308082`}, {0.3359182983747898`, 0.3202252266080714`, 
0.3061767427469966`, 0.2940938477605253`, 0.283709859405582`, 
0.2748580785260618`, 0.26738319813875666`, 0.260872981665339`, 
0.2552516206579761`, 0.24782249478634893`, 0.24506299142920446`, 
0.2515128419306529`, 0.2763667585306461`}, {0.3295856393559455`, 
0.4054474246779005`, 0.4728093810396434`, 0.5134063809878686`, 
0.5333138745142322`, 0.5430480032279276`, 0.5487423826396918`, 
0.5529829411464551`, 0.5566173670733299`, 0.5597417807658861`, 
0.5622517273279026`, 0.5633464838462574`, 0.5616964104105145`, 
0.5554888928831214`, 0.5427398185856183`}, {0.5221263952096429`, 
0.4942177548200779`, 0.46217124328270465`, 0.4307733594356792`, 
0.4042335523051115`, 0.38462253251886747`, 0.3719341799201244`, 
0.365039801860099`, 0.36255066810131026`, 0.36325840876256693`, 
0.3662575405512424`, 0.37092114290185174`, 0.37683431863786276`, 
0.38372997094566247`, 0.3914392747519866`, 0.39985697190794944`, 
0.4089182021630236`, 0.41858330402921934`, 0.42882815708967575`, 
0.4396378543249029`, 0.4510026370899692`}};
```

I tried to use for loop

```
For[j = 1, j <= Length[tab], j++,
 Drop[tab[[j]], -2]
 ]
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Please note that this is only an example - in my case the number of dropped elements is also a function of index `j` and not constant as in the example above.

What can I do?

Comment: Your function is not saving the result of `Drop`, that's the reason it's not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing you should do is to forget about using For-loops to manipulate lists. If you feel more comfortable with For-loop type thinking then you might use

```
 Table[Drop[tab[[i]], -2], {i, Length[data]}]
```

But if you are willing to learn a bit functional coding, I'd recommend

```
Drop[#, -2] & /@ tab
```

Comment: Since your answer matches with the code in my head almost completely, I shall mark it as accepted.
Btw: I would LOVE to learn functional coding. And links where to start? Sometimes it's also hard to understand your answers without understanding the details.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to get involved with a function of index `j`, you might find `MapIndexed` helpful. For example, if you want to drop `j` th element in the `j`th sublist, you can do

```
MapIndexed[Drop[#1, #2] &, tab]
```

Here `#2` is your `{j}`, and you can feed it to your function. Be aware of the difference of `{j}` and `j` in `Drop`.

Answer (score 4):

If we are to drop the first `2` elements of tab[[1]], the last `2` of `tab[[2]]`, the first `6` of `tab[[3]]` and the last `2` of `tab[[4]]` make use of `MapThread`, e.g.

```
MapThread[Drop, {tab, {2, -2, 6, -2}}]
```

> ```
> {{0.287282, 0.29287, 0.349432},
>  {0.335918, 0.320225, 0.306177, 0.294094, 0.28371, 0.274858, 
>   0.267383, 0.260873, 0.255252, 0.247822, 0.245063},
>  {0.548742, 0.552983, 0.556617, 0.559742, 0.562252, 
>   0.563346, 0.561696, 0.555489, 0.54274}, 
>  {0.522126, 0.494218, 0.462171, 0.430773, 0.404234, 0.384623, 
>   0.371934, 0.36504, 0.362551, 0.363258, 0.366258, 0.370921, 0.376834, 
>   0.38373, 0.391439, 0.399857, 0.408918, 0.418583, 0.428828}}
> ```